# Select option value - selectedchoice is not working

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js

I am binding a SELECT HTML tag with some dynamic values using knockout JS. Additionally, i am trying to set a selected choice which is failing. Please suggest where i am going wrong.

```
self.level1Choices.selectedChoice = ko.observable(2); - this line does not seem to work.
```

The JSFiddle for this code is at http://jsfiddle.net/oarp7gwj/7/
The dropdown is not loading in the JSFiddle for some reason. I dont think i have referenced the knockout JS correctly. In my local environment, I am able to load the select box with the values. However, i am not able to set the selected value.

@Wayne Ellery, @QBM5 - please advise since you know about this already :)

Comment: Please add your code that implements the binding, I see several potential problems but can be sure if they are valid with the code you provided.  Preferably recreate the issue using JSFiddle, it would make it much easier to debug

Comment: This is my first attempt at everything..ie. Azure mobile services, Knockout, JS Fiddle, etc. So hopefully i did it right. Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/az4rox0q/1/

Comment: You should update your question to include the model and also the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You should use var to declare your model object to avoid scoping issues

```
var viewModel = new DataModel();
```

The main issue was you need to add to the Datamodel by exposing it through the this variable in the Datamodel.

```
var DataModel = function (client) {
    var self = this;

    self.level1Choices = ko.observableArray();
};
```

Take a look at the Helo World example as to how to do this:

http://knockoutjs.com/examples/helloWorld.html

I've scoped this to self as it's a best practice to not worry about this referring to something else mentioned here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html.

I moved the loadAllApprovers method inside the DataModel as this is where it belongs and so that it has access to populate the datamodel.
I added the mobile services client to the constructor so that it can be mocked for testing your model.

```
var DataModel = function (client) {
    var self = this;

    self.level1Choices = ko.observableArray();

    var loadAllApprovers = function () {
        var allAppprovers = client.getTable('TABLE');

        var query = allAppprovers.select("ID", "FirstName").read().done(function (approverResults) {
            self.level1Choices(approverResults);
        }, function (err) {
            console.log("Error: " + err);
        });    
    };

    loadAllApprovers();
};
```

You were also missing knockout in your jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/az4rox0q/6/

Comment: Thanks @Wayne Ellery. You solved the issue. I am quite new to Knockout, JS, etc. So your detailed code was very useful.

Is    self.level1Choices.push the correct way to load the Select Box. Or is there some easier or better way?

Comment: self.level1Choices.push is ok. If you just wanted to load all the array into the array you could use self.level1Choices(approverResults); Please accept the answer.